# Linking two user accounts to the same exchange mailbox - exchange 2003

Tags: exchange-2003, email

Is it possible to Link two user accounts to the same exchange mailbox ? (exchange 2003)

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can give other users the rights to access it and/or send messages as the owner.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to have an alias for the mailbox username e.g. alex thomas or alexthomas ?

Comment: If you're talking about an alternate SMTP address, yes, you can have as many as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of i.e. in Active Directory/Exchange there is a one to one mapping between user accounts and exchange mailboxes

**But** you can give more than one user **access** to the same mailbox. So that if your aim is to allow multiple users to view and interact with the mail that is possible.

- When I do this I set up a new account with a mailbox e.g. MyResource@domain.com
- I set a v. complex account password that never expires (you never need to log on as this user)
- Then I give the appropriate AD usergroup (but you could do individual users) access to the mailbox. I tend to give full access but you can be more restrictive
- Then in each users Outlook profile go to Tools > Accounts > select the MS Exchange account of the user and click change
- Click More settings
- Select the advanced tab
- Click Add
- type in the mailbox name in this case MyResource

In Outlook the user will now see Mailbox - [User], Any PST archive *and* Mailbox - MyResource

This keeps that mailbox separate from their own mail. If you just want people to see inbound mail and you don't mind about duplication of effort you can create a distribution group with the email address MyResource@domain.com but UserA still sees a mail as unread even if UserB has actioned it.